# How can i optimize

Tags: c#, json

This is my code and takes long time to insert the info to a json

```
ListarRegistrosFormularioContacto: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
objLog.InsertarLog($"SolicitarReporteFormularios: { idPeticion }", $"Tiempo de carga ListarRegistrosFormularioContacto: { stopwatch.Elapsed }, por tamaño de { dtRegistros.Rows.Count }");

if (dtRegistros.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    string dataSerialize = "[";

    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Restart();

    for (int x = 0; x < dtRegistros.Rows.Count; x++)
    {
        if (x > 0) { dataSerialize += ", "; }

        dynamic registro = new ExpandoObject();

        for (int col = 0; col < dtRegistros.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            AddPropertyToExpadoObject(registro, dtRegistros.Columns[col].ColumnName, dtRegistros.Rows[x][col].ToString());
        }

        dataSerialize += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(registro);
    }

    stopwatch.Stop();

    objLog.InsertarLog($"SolicitarReporteFormularios: { idPeticion }", $"Tiempo de termino de lectura de registros ( for ) : { stopwatch.Elapsed }");

    dataSerialize += "]";

    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Restart();

    string filename = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")}.json";
    string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Files/reporte-formulario.json");
    File.WriteAllText(path: path, contents: dataSerialize);

    stopwatch.Stop();

    objLog.InsertarLog($"SolicitarReporteFormularios: { idPeticion }", $"Pinta los registros en el archivo json : { stopwatch.Elapsed }");

    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Restart();
```

Any idea guys? My SQL is fast, take seconds but this conversion to json 5min or more

So the other problem (because the time) is my App Service is sending timeout (230 seconds for every petition)

The data is from 11k-25k rows and the time is spend in the conversion from the results from SQL to JSON.

**The problem was solved with Stringbuilder guys, i paste the code tomorrow, thank you!**

Now is:

[image: New code]

So with this the time was only 20 seconds, thank you for the help guys

Comment: which part is slow? dont include the parts which does not have problem so that we can focus on the actual problem

Comment: Sounds like you might have a better time with `Dictionary<string, string>` than with ExpandoObjects...

Comment: Maybe you could try going with async functions? I'm not sure why is this slow I would think that the for is making it slow as it has to loop through lots of things?

Comment: Why not serialize `dtRegistros` directly as a single whole?

Comment: How much data is contained in DataTable? | At least you should use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Looks like you are manually serializing data; don't do that. Just serialize using the built-in serializers.

Comment: Hi guys. The data is from 11k to 25k registers +-

Comment: Also, if the code works and you're willing to share all of it, you should check [the help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to see if your question is on topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: @Slvr update your question with this 11k to 25k information.  don't just reply in comments, improve the question.

Comment: For sure, i will share the code if it works

Comment: have you tried serializing the DataTable directly `string dataSerialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtRegistros);` ?

Comment: As others have said,  Definately use StringBuilder,  and I'd avoid ExpandoObject as it adds a lot of overhead.and your model is very simple.    If necessary use Dictionary<string,string>, but given your model is so simple, I'd just use StringBuilder alone and add each row/object/column manually to the StringBuilder.  Should be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with the StringBuilder as the coments says. From 17min to 20 seconds